# How to rename files recursively with a specific extension to remove unwanted characters in audio files

Tags: find, rename, ffmpeg, special-characters

I want to rename files with a `.m4a` extension recursively in child directories to remove unwanted characters in audio files such as [ **`'`** ].

That's because that this below happened to this file  `04 Tears Don't Fall.m4a` without the other files:

> Could not load file 2005-09-30 - The Poison (Deluxe Edition) [US -
> 88697-09021-2 - 2007]/04 Tears Don't Fall.m4a. Maybe it is not a
> supported file format?
> When trying to load using ffmpeg, got the following error: FFmpeg
> could not read the file.

Comment: After renaming, It still throws the same error. Maybe A corrupted track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
for fn in **/*\'*.m4a; do echo mv "$fn" "${fn/\'/}"; done
```

`echo` is needed for checking the result before real renaming.

Comment: This worked fully.

Answer (score 4):

There must be some other issue at work, because `ffmpeg` is perfectly able to read filenames containing single quotes:

```
mkdir '2005-09-30 - The Poison (Deluxe Edition) [US - 88697-09021-2 - 2007]'
cp -p {another.m4a} "2005-09-30 - The Poison (Deluxe Edition) [US - 88697-09021-2 - 2007]/04 Tears Don't Fall.m4a"

ffmpeg -i "2005-09-30 - The Poison (Deluxe Edition) [US - 88697-09021-2 - 2007]/04 Tears Don't Fall.m4a"

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2005-09-30 - The Poison (Deluxe Edition) [US - 88697-09021-2 - 2007]/04 Tears Don't Fall.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: M4A mp42isom
...
```

Maybe you're not quoting properly. Unfortunately without seeing your code it's not possible to verify this, only flag it as a possible issue.

However, if you really want to rename the files to remove a set of characters, you can use code like this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.m4a' -exec \
    sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do echo mv "$f" "${f'"//[\']/"'}"; done' _ {} +
```

Remove `echo` when you are ready to execute the `mv`.

The `[\']` range can be extended to include additional characters that are to be removed. For example, you might choose `` [\'\\\"\\\`:] `` to remove single and double quotes, backticks, and colons. (Single quotes must be prefixed with `\` ; double quotes, backticks, and dollar symbols must be prefixed with `\\\`.)

Comment: FFmpeg was being used in demucs python module, so there is no way to quote it as far as I know.

Comment: After renaming, It still throws the same error. Maybe A corrupted track.

Answer (score 2):

First of all we write a shell script that move $1 to $1 without (') and we call it special_move.sh. Do not forget to give the file execution permission.

```
#!/bin/bash

orgFile=$1
destFile=${orgFile//\'/}

echo "mv $orgFile $destFile"
#mv $orgFile $destFile
```

Then move to root dir where files are stored and type cmd

```
find . -name "*'*.m4a" -exec /absolute/path/special_move.sh {} \;
```

It test is satisfying, uncomment last row of script file.

Comment: You'd want to read [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)